# Cannot find type 'ListenerRegistration' in scope

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can't quite understand why this isn't working.

I have:

```
Import Firebase
```

...up at the top. Followed by:

```
class MessageViewController: MessagesViewController
{
    
    private var messages: [Message] = []
    private var messageListener: ListenerRegistration?
```

And it's giving me the error:

> Cannot find type 'ListenerRegistration' in scope

I checked the docs and ListenerRegistration doesn't appear to be deprecated... so why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListenerRegistration` is part of the `FirebaseFirestore` package. You will need to:

```
import FirebaseFirestore
```